# how to insert Hex as argument to gdb? (as arg, not as stdin)

Tags: linux, gdb

I want to do the next bash command, but actually in gdb (so i can debug it):

```
myProgram "`echo -en '\x41\x41\x41\x41'`"
```

**I'm trying to do this (in gdb):**

```
(dbg) run "`echo -en "\x41\x41\x41\x41"`"
```

i DON'T mean the stdin redirect:

```
echo -en "\x41\x41\x41\x41" > command_output.txt
gdb myProgram
(gdb) run < command_output.txt
```

how to insert Hex values as an agrument to a program in gdb?

Answer (score 0):

you may try

```
(dbg) run $(echo -en "\x41\x41\x41\x41")
```

Comment: this doesn't work for me.. :(
I get this:

starting program: myProgram $(echo -en "\x41\x41\x41\x41")

but it doesnt seem to behave as expected...

Comment: `info args` shows: `argc=3`. `print *argv@argc` shows that the 2nd arg is `-en` and the 3rd arg is `\\x41\\x41\\x41\\x41`

Answer (score 0):

The gdb `set args` command can set the arguments. Using `eval`, which runs its arguments through `printf`, we can insert almost arbitrary characters using hex escapes. (We're limited by the fact that gdb will typically invoke the target using a shell, so it helps to add single quotes around each argument).

```
(gdb) eval "set args '%s'", "\x41\x41\x20\x41"
You can't do that without a process to debug.
```

That's another gdb limitation. An alternative that doesn't make gdb want to allocate memory in the target is to give eval only `%c` conversions and integer arguments, like this:

```
(gdb) eval "set args '%c%c%c%c'", 0x41, 0x41, 0x20, 0x41
```

But having to put the exact number of `%c` conversions into that format string is tedious, so let's stick with the single `%s`. We need to start the process, even though we're going to restart it right after we set the args using eval.

```
(gdb) start
Starting program: /home/mp/argprint

Temporary breakpoint 1, main (argc=1, argv=0x7ffffffee2b8) at argprint.c:4
4               for(int i=0; i < argc; i++) {

(gdb) eval "set args '%s'", "\x41\x41\x20\x41"
(gdb) run
The program being debugged has been started already.
Start it from the beginning? (y or n) y
Starting program: /home/mp/argprint 'AA A'
arg 0 is <</home/mp/argprint>>
arg 1 is <<AA A>>
```

If you have an old gdb that doesn't have the eval command but does have Python, you can do this:

```
(gdb) python gdb.execute("set args '\x41\x41\x20\x41'")
```

Comment: I get `Undefined command: "eval"` :( thank you for the explenations though

Comment: I'll see if there are other ways to do it. What is the output of `gdb --version` ?

Comment: output of `gdb --version` is: `GNU (GDB) 7.0.1-debian ... This GDB was configured as "i486-linux-gnu"...`

Comment: I've edited the answer to include a solution using Python.